# Slow user input on firefox, but not chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox, input

I have a web page with a little over 1000 text inputs and 100 check boxes created in the following way:

`echo"<td><input type='text' id='".$a."-".$b."-inc"."' autocomplete='off'></td>";`

the input freezes momentarily when switching between input elements and typing. at first i thought the problem was that firefox retains information on refresh, but with the autocomplete property it no longer does.

when i check the profiler the profiler says messageQueue.push is the culprit.

I am especially confused as chrome is perfectly fine.

any idea what is slowing the input and how to fix it?

Comment: There is 1 form I never want to have to fill out.....

Comment: Are you using Firebug on the site? Try to turn it off, if the problem goes away just live with it during development.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you are using a table. Use div's instead of tables, that's a lot faster.

```
echo "<div><input type='text' id='".$a."-".$b."-inc"."' autocomplete='off'></div>";
```